# sql select top 5 every month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table of the format, let's call it product_revenue
Product_id, year, month, revenue

and i need to get the following columns:
year, month, revenue_top_5_monthly

where revenue_top_5_monthly is the sum of revenue of the products that had the highest revenue in that month. The top 5 products vary from month to month.

I can do this for a single month by selecting with a sub-query a single month, sorting by revenue and using limit 5, then summing up the value, but I wouldn't know how to do this for every month in a single query

What I have is

```
select 'y' as year, 'x' as month, sum(revenue) as revenue_top_5 from
(select revenue from product_revenue
where month=x and year=y
order by revenue desc
limit 5) as top5
```

but I need it for every month in one shot.

The product_revenue table has over 10m rows for 16 months, so final query speed is of large relevance. For one month it currently takes about 80-100 sec, and I have to run about 30 such queries, each for the whole 16 months, in a 1h 30min slot.

as suggested, I also tried

```
select * from
(
select dd.year, dd.monthnumber,
u.product_id, sum(revenue) as revenue
from source
group by 1,2,3
)a
where 
(select count(*) from
                            (select dd.year, dd.monthnumber,
                            u.product_id, sum(revenue) as revenue
                            from source
                            group by 1,2,3)b
where b.year=a.year and b.monthnumber=a.monthnumber and b.revenue<=a.revenue
)<=5
```

but returns no rows. The individual subqueries a and b return the expected rows as named.

Comment: Sounds like you need a composite index on `(year, month)`

Comment: it's coming from a date dimension table, separate indexes vs composite index would only affect performance, not output number of rows, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from
(select 
@rn:=if(@prv=product_id, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
@prv:=product_id as product_id,
year, 
month,
revenue
from tbl
join
(select @prv:=0, @rn:=0)tmp
order by 
product_id, revenue desc) a
where rid<=5
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa171/3)**:

```
| RID | PRODUCT_ID | YEAR | MONTH | REVENUE |
---------------------------------------------
|   1 |          1 | 2013 |     1 |     100 |
|   2 |          1 | 2013 |     1 |      90 |
|   3 |          1 | 2013 |     1 |      70 |
|   4 |          1 | 2013 |     1 |      60 |
|   5 |          1 | 2013 |     1 |      50 |
|   1 |          2 | 2013 |     1 |    5550 |
|   2 |          2 | 2013 |     1 |     550 |
|   3 |          2 | 2013 |     1 |     520 |
|   4 |          2 | 2013 |     1 |     510 |
|   5 |          2 | 2013 |     1 |     150 |
```

Comment: 2 years later and this is still useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
   SELECT t1.year,
          t1.month,
          (SELECT SUM(t2.revenue) 
           FROM product_revenue t2
           WHERE t2.month = t1.month
           AND t2.year = t1.year
           ORDER BY t2.revenue DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS revenue_top_5
   FROM product_revenue t1
   GROUP BY  t1.year, t1.month
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this and c.

```
select top 5 'y' as year,'x' as month,sum(total) as top_5 From
(select sum(revenue) as total from product_revenue
where month=x and year=y
order by revenue desc) as t
```

Comment: the word "TOP" is for SQL Server it wont work for MySQL, in MYSQL you have to do it with limits