# Newest 5 per group with fulltext search

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have some table more than 300,000 records, the table structure:

```
id  |  title | source | description | date | fullindex
```

id is PRIMARY key, date has added index, source has added index, fullindex has added full-text index.

Now I want to make a query. newest 5 per group with fulltext search.

I have tried

```
SELECT 'a' as t_name,id,title,source,description,date,fullindex 
FROM table1 a1
WHERE MATCH (fullindex) AGAINST ('+bool' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
and 6>(select count(*) from table1 where source=a1.source and date>a1.date)
```

but this query would cost 6.5987s, the affection is very low.

So how to make a quicker query?

PS: I have searched `mysql greatest n per group` in google, but with my limited skill, I did not make a better code for myself, waiting some mysql master for a help.

Comment: You can go this similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560770/sql-select-top-5-every-month/16561220#16561220   Post if you have any doubts in it.

Comment: @Meherzad, so where to add `MATCH (fullindex) AGAINST ('+bool' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`?

Comment: Add within the inner query that gives records to the `from` part of the outer query.

Comment: @Meherzad, 17.2221s, such a slowly query.

Comment: @Meherzad, `SELECT 'a' as t_name,id,title,source,description,date,fullindex from
(select 
@rn:=if(@prv=source, @rn+1, 1) as rid,
@prv:=source as source,
 'a' as t_name,id,title,description,date,fullindex
from it_nt1
join
(select @prv:=0, @rn:=0)tmp
order by 
source, date desc) a
where rid<=5 and MATCH (fullindex) AGAINST ('+bool' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` is my code right?

Comment: Check my answer add the full text search in the inner part.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30017/discussion-between-fish-man-and-meherzad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT @rn:=if(@pv=source, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
'a' t_name,id,title,@pv:=source,description,date,fullindex 
FROM table1 a1
JOIN (SELECT @pv:=0, @rId:=0)tmp
WHERE MATCH (fullindex) AGAINST ('+bool' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY source, date)a
WHERE a.rId <=5;
```

Add compound index on (source, date)

Hope this helps..

Comment: `ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD INDEX `index1` (`date`, `source`);` run your code, why each source still output more than 5 results? checked, some are 10.