# Google Sheets: select top n daily values over entire year

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets raw data set of 5 columns over a 2 year time period:

1. Col A: year (2017...2018)
2. Col B: month (1...12)
3. Col C: day of month (1...31)
4. Col D: hour of day (0...23)
5. Col E: hourly electricity consumption (0.00-9999.99)

What I'd like to extract is the top 3 hours of highest electricity consumption of each and every day (i.e. 3 points * 365 days/year * 2 years = 2190 of the rows).

I know how to either:

- Get the top 3 consumption hours within a single day:

```
    =QUERY(A1:E23, "select A,B,C,D,E order by E desc limit 3") for the first day
    =QUERY(A24:E47, "select A,B,C,D,E order by E desc limit 3") for the second day, etc.
```

- or get the highest (single) consumption hour of each and every day, without knowing during which hour it occurs:

```
    =QUERY(A1:E, "select A,B,C,max(E) group by A,B,C")
```

How do I combine the two, so I still capture all info (all columns)?

Comment: Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560770/sql-select-top-5-every-month) but my data is in google sheets, not on an sql server.

Comment: tricky without a sample to work with.  here's a blank sheet.  Could you paste a represenatative sample in here?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO09VURFa6BhJ2f2JCPvWQERKszPGNng54GNO22b5cc/edit

Comment: I guess would be easier to do using app scripts. Are you open to that solution?
Also please share a sheet with some sample data. It would be easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some sample data on a tab called Data on [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO09VURFa6BhJ2f2JCPvWQERKszPGNng54GNO22b5cc/edit#gid=2100307022).

Then I put this formula in cell B1 on the tab called MK.Help Top 3.

```
=FILTER(Data!A:E,COUNTIFS(Data!A:A,Data!A:A,Data!B:B,Data!B:B,Data!C:C,Data!C:C,Data!E:E,">="&Data!E:E)<=3)
```

Countifs() is useful for creating a sort of ranking.

Comment: Thnk you Matt, this does exactly what I need it to do. I had no idea COUNTIFS() could be used like that - clever application!